# History Stack of activity clear in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I need to clear the back history of activities.
I have 5 Activities.
   In the first 4 activities I have to make the back button go to and fro with data filled in all the screens. But as I proceed on 5th screen I need to reset the back history and start intent with new stack. So that after i press back in my 5th screen app should exit. I tried using launchMode , Nohistory and Flags such as `NEW_TASK` , `CLEAR_TOP`, `CLEAR_TASK` but still unable to achieve this. Please help me. Suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please show, how did you try those flags ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri  I am writing the flags as below.  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.Class); i.addFlags(android.flags.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_NEW_TASK | FLAG_CLEAR_TASK) and then startactivity;  then this.finish();  This is finishing my activity (i.e. MAinActivity ) but not the activities  before this. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: See the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments you suggested that you've tried using flags like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.Class);     
i.addFlags(android.flags.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_NEW_TASK | FLAG_CLEAR_TASK)
```

But instead try using them like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.Class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: Not working... :( . Solved my problem by using the ctx of the activity and calling finish like MyActivity.ctx.finish before starting new intent. Hope this will be helpful to somebody.